# Socket.emit with callback in Android - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to communicate with NodeJS server using SocketIO in Server and Android. Currently using [Gottox SocketIO-Java-Client Repository](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)

NODEJS:

```
 socket.on('new user',function(data, callback){
    if (nicknames.indexOf(data)!=-1){
        callback(false);
    } else{
        callback(true);
        socket.nickname = data;
        nicknames.push(socket.nickname);
        updateNicknames();
    }
});
```

Android:

```
socket.emit("new user", "User01");
```

Now if I use the above code, callback error occurs at callback(true) as shown in the following link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKcog.png

Please suggest on how to implement callbacks in Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java client is not providing a callback. The client method should look like this:

```
socket.emit("new user", new IOAcknowledge() {
    public void ack(Object...args) {

    }
}, "User01");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this worked for me keep in mind that callback is in other thread

```
mSocket.emit("newuser", email, new Ack() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.i("callback","test");
    }
});
```